# Probability of card sequence with no adjacent cards of same color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this problem:

We have deck of 32 cards, 16 cards are red and 16 black, what is the probability of such arrangment of cards that no adjacent cards have same number.

My try:

We care only about colours, so we can say that there are $\binom{32}{16}$ possible ways how to arrange red and black cards (we are choosing positions of either red or black cards) and there are exactly two valid solutions:
RBRB....RB and BRBR....BR. So we have ${2/\binom{32}{16}}$

Is that corect? If not, where have I made mistake?

Comment: The solution is correct, if it really is colour. In the post, there is mention of number, which is puzzling.  If the cards of each colour are numbered $1$ to $16$, and you want no two identical numbers to be adjacent, you have a much harder problem.